# Any score that computes basical statistical differences between prediction and test target values?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Using LinearRegression from sklearn to predict values.
Using model.accuracy_score to find the accuracy of the model predictions.

In one case, the accuracy score is reasonable (71%) but the problem was found in the range of values.

Test values were from min = 40541 to max = 349313 whereas, Prediction values were from min = -4638 to 528096. Mean values of both sets were around 181000.

This problem does not expect negative values in Predictions. This was not captured by the accuracy_score or by the mean.

Is there any ready score which will compare min, max of two sets and give some measure of how close they are? or capture values out of range from the test values?

Comment: What are these values ? Did you think of **normalizing** your train and test sets ?